# Scan Ethereum transactions for known addresses over JSON-RPC

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

I want to scan all Ethereum transactions over JSON-RPC API and build a balance tree and transaction map for the address list I know.

What are the most efficient calls to do this? Is there anything more performant than `getBlock()` followed by `getTransaction()` for each transaction? Is there way to filter transactions, so that I would only list transactions concerning my addresses over JSON-RPC?